# How to automatically populate a field according to another field in a different model in Odoo13?

Tags: python, odoo

I am building a model named "Wrap"(similar to product packagings) which allows users to create a wrap for each selected product from the sale order line tree.

```
from odoo import models, fields, api, _


class Wrap(models.Model):
    _name = 'sale.wrap'
    _description = 'wraps in SO tree view'

    name = fields.Char(string='Name', required=True)
    product = fields.Many2one('product.product', string='Product')
    quantity = fields.Integer()

class SaleOrderWrap(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order.line'

    wrap = fields.Many2one('sale.wrap', string='Wrap')
```

I had added the field named wraps to the sale order line tree which directs users to the wrap create form.

[image: wrap create form with product field which has to be updated]

Now I want the product field in this model to get automatically updated according to the corresponding product in that sale order line, how is this done.

[image: Selected product in sale order line tree]

I am learning this framework myself and this is the only help I can get, please help, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `default` values in the context:

```
<field name="wrap" context="{'default_field_name': field_value}"
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use `onchange` method

```
warp = fields.Many2one('sale.order.line','Warp')
```

like :

```
@api.onchange('product')
def onchange_product(self):
   res = []
   for rec in self :
     vals = {'name':rec.value1,'field2':rec.line.value2,etc}
     res.append(vals)
```